# How do i prove this equality using boolean algebra?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

$x'yx' + (x' + y')' = y''y$

I don't know how to prove this to be true? 
Any help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x'yx' = x'y=x'x'y=x'y$ by commutativity and idempotency. $(x'+y')' = x''y'' = xy$ by De Morgan and double negation, and $y''y=yy = y$ by double negation and idempotency.

Comment: thank you, that helped quite a bit!